# Update help page according to the new closing phrasing

Tags: discussion, status-completed, help-center

When a question is closed, a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) is provided to help the asker improving the question.

The differents categories are listed but some of them don't fit anymore the new closing reason :

- ***unclear what you're asking*** being now ***needs details or clarity***
- ***too broad*** being now ***needs to be more focused***

Although there is a small description in the question about the reason of the closing, the help page about closed question could be rephrased in order to find the detailed reason easily for new users

Comment: Help pages have been updated now that the new post notices are [live across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide). Thank you!