# A user with less than 3k reputation cast a reopen vote on their own question

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

How did a user with ~400 reputation cast a vote to reopen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304446)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's explicitly permitted by the privilege of being able to view close votes.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

> **You may also cast a close or reopen vote on your questions.** With the close/reopen vote privilege, you'll be able to see (and cast) close and reopen votes on all questions.

This wouldn't translate to someone being able to cast a reopen vote on someone *else's* question, which is what I think you're conflating here.

Comment: Never knew about this, thanks. (They should probably fix the *"It takes **5** close votes from members of the community with the close vote privilege to close a question"* in that page)

Comment: Unfortunately, @adiga, I'm not sure they can. As I understand it, the Help Center pages are common/shared across all Stack Exchange sites, and Stack Overflow is the only site where the close-vote threshold is 3. I don't think the Help Center infrastructure supports a site-specific exception. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342473/

Comment: @CodyGray it's updated in this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions *"When a question reaches 3 close votes, it is marked as being Closed, and will no longer accept answers"*

Comment: @adiga Ah, fair point. I'm not sure then, looks like it should be possible to fix. My ["get it" girl](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391899/update-help-page-according-to-the-new-closing-phrasing#comment743690_391899) for things like this has unfortunately [moved on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392037/where-did-megan-risdals-diamond-go). :-(